# Socket.io send data to global variable

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to make a multiplayer game and I'm having an issue where everything the server returns is being contained inside of the function.
I'm trying to return the data to a global variable on the client side.

```
<script>
    let test = "no";
    let socket = io();
    socket.on('player',function(data){
        test =  data;
    });
    console.log(test); // says no instead of yes     
</script>
```

Comment: The ONLY place you can reliably use the `data` that arrives with the `player` message is INSIDE that message handler.  That's the way asynchronous operations work.  Put the code that wants to use that data inside that message handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.on is an async call, thus

```
<script>
    let test = "no";
    let socket = io();
    socket.on('player',function(data){
        test =  data;
        **console.log(test);**  //say yes and also return it here
    });
   // console.log(test); // says no instead of yes , will not work as async

</script>
```

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the async properties of socket.io, but since I'm new I'm not really sure how to work around it. So I have to return the data variable in the player function? How would I go about returning it?